# How do I get Pillow module to work on Python 2?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using a Mac with Yosemite.

"from PIL import Image" works in my terminal, but it doesn't work in Sublime. When I run it in sublime, I get "ImportError: No module named PIL"

"import Image" doesn't work either. I really want this to work with sublime, but I'm not even sure if it's a problem with the editor even though it seems to work in terminal.

Comment: What does ``PIL.__file__`` say at the Python shell in your terminal? And what does ``sys.path`` look like in Sublime's Python shell?